# What's the difference between session.setAttribute and request.setAttribute?

Tags: java, servlets

What's the difference between `session.setAttribute` and `request.setAttribute`?

Comment: The scope..., session attribute live all the session and the request attribute only in a request

Comment: Both use a key/value pair mechanism to store attribute values associating with corresponding keys. The difference is in the scope.

Comment: Does it matter which one I use, when passing an attribute from a servlet to a jsp?

Comment: Why not? If you store a variable in a request, it will disappear (destroy) when the request is over. If you store a variable in a session, it will disappear (destroy) when the session is over. Request attributes are extensively used in MVC architecture.

Comment: @ThePhantom05  it is good to use request attribute.If you want to access that variable in another page or in another request then use session

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scope, 
session attribute live all the session and the request attribute only in a request

Comment: Session attributes must be serializeable (it is very bad not to do so) because they can be unloaded to the hard drive or transferred to the another cluster node. Request attributes stays in RAM on the same JVM and has no such a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Difference lies in the scope. Request-scoped attribute is visible only while current request is processed. Session attribute is persistent between several requests from the same user. Session support mechanisms may differ (the most widespread are cookie based), but all of them guarantee session attrigbute persistence until user's session stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Request attribute is only available in the `request` object lifetime.
`filters, servlet, jsp, include, forward` uses same request object.
Once the request is completed, request object is destroyed.

Whereas session attributes are available till the session ends or till the browser is closed. Hence the difference lies in the scope.

For example, the flow like *page1->page2->page3->page4*. `session.setAttribute` will make the key available in all pages. But if we use `request.setAttribute` in page2, then only page3 can get the key value set in page2.

`request.setAttribute()` may help you in getting rid of the hidden fields.